# Django Wiki image restore

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wiki

in address : wiki\plugins\images\templates\wiki\plugins\images 
File : index.html
line : #86

```html
{% if image|can_write:user and old_revision != image.current_revision %}
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="fa fa-refresh"></span>
                    {% trans "Revert to this version" %}
                  </a>
                {% endif %}
```

the href is empty and the code is  not doing anything. It has to restore the deleted images!
does any one knows how to fix the problem?

Comment: We need more details, what wiki is this and what do you mean with "href is empty"? You're setting `href="#"`.

Comment: https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki   please check this out .